# Firebase RTDB data not showing up in SwiftUI List view

Tags: swift, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I was following an internet tutorial on putting Firebase data into a list view in SwiftUI but the tutorial used Firestore so I'm on my own now. I have all of the data but when I open the `PlayerListView` the list is empty. However, when I print, all of the data prints perfectly.

Here's what I have:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct Player: Identifiable {
  var id: String = UUID().uuidString
  var username: String
  var score: Int
}

struct PlayerListView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel = PlayerViewModel()
  @Binding var showLeaderboard: Bool

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(viewModel.players) { player in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
          Text(player.username)
            .font(.headline)
          Text("\(player.score)")
            .font(.subheadline)
        }
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("Players")
        .onAppear() {
            self.viewModel.fetchData() { player in
                print(player)
            }
        }
    }
    .onTapGesture {
      self.showLeaderboard.toggle()
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
class PlayerViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var players = [Player]()
  let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users")
    
  func fetchData(completion: @escaping(Array<Player>) -> Void) {
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
      if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
        for child in result {
          let orderID = child.key
          self
            .ref
            .child(orderID)
            .queryOrdered(byChild: "score")
            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
              let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
              self.players.append(
                Player(id: .init(), 
                       username: value?["username"] as? String ?? "", 
                       score: value?["score"] as? Int ?? 0))
              completion(self.players)
            })
          }
        }
      })  
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try publishing the `players` array on the main thread: `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.players.append(...) }`

Comment: Just tried that and still nothing shows up

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified your code a bit (no need to implement a completion handler, for example), and fixed a few issues.

The biggest issue was that you didn't map the player ID to the `id` attribute of your `Player` struct. As `List` requires its elements to be identifiable, all elements must have unique IDs. All players had the same ID (an empty string), however - and this led to duplicate entries in the `List` view.

Here is the updated code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct Player: Identifiable {
  var id: String = UUID().uuidString
  var username: String
  var score: Int
}

struct PlayerListView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel = PlayerViewModel()
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List(viewModel.players) { player in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
          Text(player.username)
            .font(.headline)
          Text("\(player.score)")
            .font(.subheadline)
        }
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("Players")
      .onAppear() {
        self.viewModel.fetchData()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
import Foundation
import Firebase

class PlayerViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var players = [Player]()
  let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users")
  
  func fetchData() {
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
      if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
        for child in result {
          let orderID = child.key
          self
            .ref
            .child(orderID)
            .queryOrdered(byChild: "score")
            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
              let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
              self.players.append(
                Player(id: value?["id"] as? String ?? UUID().uuidString,
                       username: value?["username"] as? String ?? "",
                       score: value?["score"] as? Int ?? 0))
            })
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Here is how my test data looks like:

[image: Firebase RTDB data model]

And here is a snapshot of the UI in the simulator:

[image: Snapshot of the UI]